# Nobel novelists and Nigerian nations

Tags: crosswords

[image: crossword]

> 1. Nobel novelist
> 2. Baked bread
> 3. Middle-Eastern marketplace
> 4. Convicted comedian
> 5. Female fowl
> 6. Nigerian nation
> 7. Sonny actor; actor Scott
> 8. Liechtenstein locality
> 9. Spanish she
> 10. Cavalry creature
> 11. Halfish hectare
> 12. Ferrari founder
> 13. Small market segment
> 14. IT business model
> 15. Manchester manager Van
> 16. Scandinavian car
> 17. Discredited deity
> 18. Multi-married monarch
> 19. Academy Award Reed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my answer

> [image]

not sure if there is more to it

> 1. Hesse
>  2. naan
>  3. bazaar
>  4. Cosby
>  5. hen
>  6. igbo
>  7. Caan
>  8. Schaan
>  9. ella
>  10. horse
>  11. acre
>  12. Enzo
>  13. niche
>  14. SaaS (software as a service)
>  15. Gaal
>  16. Saab
>  17. Baal
>  18. Henry
>  19. Donna

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

I had no idea what the answer to 7 18 and 19 were, 18 was just an educated guess on my part.